# File Structure MEAN .IO After mean init MyApp

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

After setting up `node bower grunt and mean` I run `mean init myApp` which prepares me a new project. At that point I go into the app and run 
`npm install`

After my project is installed I can run the app with no problems and everything looks great. But the amount of files and folders is a bit overwhelming. I have searched for a tutorial explaining the file paths but can't find one that matches my current build after following those commands right off of the mean.io website.

```
 $ sudo npm install -g mean-cli 
  $ mean init yourNewApp
```

Someone please provide me with some documentation to read through to understand what's being installed following those commands and how to weed through it to understand how to start working with mean.io

The file structure is int he picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Config is for env-based and global configuration.
- Gulp is the gulp scripts for running \ updating \ minifying
- Logs contain the application's logs
- node_modules contain npm dependencies (standard)
- Packages contain core and custom packages
- Tests contain the test configuration files
- Tools contain general scripts like npm's postinstall actions (for example, propagating bower install to all packages)

[The documentation](http://learn.mean.io/) describes the folder structure for packages (which is almost the only interesting folder in terms of functionality development):
[image: packages file structure]

Also, [John Webb](https://github.com/rjVapes) has a couple of useful mean.io video tutorials which might help you find your way around mean.io:

1. [Getting Started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIj_Skg7eWw)
2. [Customization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aMNWYpG5sk)